# Dúvida sobre importação/exportação no ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, importação

Por que o código abaixo não funciona? Estou usando o `import`/`export` no padrão ES6 em um ambiente Node.js com o sucrase.

Arquivo `config.js`:

```
const token = 'example';
export default { token };
```

Outro arquivo qualquer:

```
import { token } from './config';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sintaxe { token } de um `import`  **não é** a [desestruturação de um objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao#Desestrutura%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_objeto). Portanto, você deve exportar o valor `token` desse modo:

```js
export const token = 'example';
```

E importá-lo assim:

```js
import { token } from './my-module';
```

Comment: Usando a sintaxe que você passou, o arquivo config.js teria vários comandos "export const". Não sei se isso é um problema quanto a legibilidade, mas existe alguma forma de exportar várias constantes em um único comando e que podem ser recuperadas posteriormente como se fosse uma desestruturação?

Comment: Com a sintaxe de módulos atual do ES6, creio que não... Verificarei mais tarde e conforme for, edito a minha resposta.

Comment: Consegui fazer com "export {valor1, valor2}". Eu havia testado antes, mas o Eslint estava acusando erro de estilo e eu achei que era problema do código.